# Prevent files to be moved by another process in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have problem with bash script.
I have two cron tasks, which gets some number of files from same folder for further processing.

```
ls -1h "targdir/*.json" | head -n ${LIMIT} > ${TMP_LIST_FILE}
while read REMOTE_FILE 
do
    mv $REMOTE_FILE $SCRDRL
done < "${TMP_LIST_FILE}"
rm -f "${TMP_LIST_FILE}"
```

But then two instances of script run simultaneously same file beeing moved to $SRCDRL which different for instances.
The question is how to prevent files to be moved by different script?

**UPD:**
Maybe I was little uncleare...
I have folder "targdir" where I store json files. And I have two cron tasks which gets some files from that directory to process. For example in targdir exists 25 files first cron task should get first 10 files and move them to /tmp/task1, second cron task should get next 10 files and move them to /tmp/task2 , e.t.c. 
But now first 10 files moves to /tmp/task1 and /tmp/task2.

Comment: Why do you have _two_ tasks getting files from the same directory? Either the tasks do exactly the same thing and than 1 should do, or the tasks do different things, but than it's kind of random which one will process any given file and that does not make sense.

Comment: It's some kind of loadbalancing. Program which processing files after that kan accept limeted number of files. But hardware allow to run it twice..

Comment: A file can only be moved once. If the first invocation moves the file to `/tmp/task1`, the second will not find it and not do anything with it. So you'll get first 10 files spread across `/tmp/task1` and `/tmp/task2` somewhat randomly, but each file will only be there once. If you need first 10 in `/tmp/task1` and second 10 in `/tmp/task2`, than you'll have to do some synchronization.

Comment: Would it make sense to make the two `cron` jobs avoid each other? Like if you have numeric file names, one would only touch files which match `[0-4]*` and the other would only touch files which match the wildcard `[5-9]*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost: **rename is atomic**. It is **not** possible for a file to be moved twice. One of the moves will fail, because the file is no longer there. If the scripts run in parallel, both list the same 10 files and instead of first 10 files moved to `/tmp/task1` and next 10 to `/tmp/task2` you may get 4 moved to `/tmp/task1` and 6 to `/tmp/task2`. Or maybe 5 and 5 or 9 and 1 or any other combination. But **each file will only end up in one task**.

So nothing is incorrect; each file is still processed only once. But it will be inefficient, because you could process 10 files at a time, but you are only processing 5. If you want to make sure you always process 10 if there is enough files available, you will have to do some synchronization. There are basically two options:

1. Place lock around the list+copy. This is most easily done using [`flock`(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) and a lock file. There are two ways to call that too:

   1. Call the whole copying operation via flock:

      ```
      flock targdir -c copy-script
      ```

      This requires that you make the part that should be excluded a separate script.
   2. Lock via file descriptor. Before the copying, do

      ```
      exec 3>targdir/.lock
      flock 3
      ```

      and after it do

      ```
      flock -u 3
      ```

      This lets you lock over part of the script only. This does not work in Cygwin (but you probably don't need that).
2. Move the files one by one until you have enough.

   ```
   ls -1h targdir/*.json > ${TMP_LIST_FILE}
   #                   ^^^ do NOT limit here
   COUNT=0
   while read REMOTE_FILE 
   do
       if mv $REMOTE_FILE $SCRDRL 2>/dev/null; then
           COUNT=$(($COUNT + 1))
       fi
       if [ "$COUNT" -ge "$LIMIT" ]; then
           break
       fi
   done < "${TMP_LIST_FILE}"
   rm -f "${TMP_LIST_FILE}"
   ```

   The `mv` will sometimes fail, in which case you don't count the file and try to move the next one, assuming the `mv` failed because the file was meanwhile moved by the other script. Each script copies at most `$LIMIT` files, but it may be rather random selection.

On a side-note if you don't absolutely need to set environment variables in the `while` loop, you can do without a temporary file. Simply:

```
ls -1h targdir/*.json | while read REMOTE_FILE
do
    ...
done
```

You can't propagate variables out of such loop, because as part of a pipeline it runs in subshell.

If you do need to set environment variables and can live with using bash specifically (I usually try to stick to `/bin/sh`), you can also write

```
while read REMOTE_FILE
do
    ...
done <(ls -1h targdir/*.json)
```

In this case the loop runs in current shell, but this kind of redirection is bash extension.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that two cron jobs move the same file to the same path should not matter for you unless you are disturbed by the error you get from one of them (one will succeed and the other will fail).

You can ignore the error by using:

```
    ...
    mv $REMOTE_FILE $SCRDRL 2>/dev/null
    ...
```

Comment: No - path is different for two cron tasks. For example for task1 $srcdrl will be /tmp/task1 and for task2 $srcdrl will be /tmp/task2. As result - one file will be processed twice. That case I trying to avoid.

Comment: Wait a moment — which "path is different" and which "folder is the same"?  You state one thing in your question and another in your comment here.  Please explain.

Comment: @USeTi: Once moved, a file will not be moved again so you should not care.

Comment: @USeTi: If the path is different, how will the same path be processed twice? I really don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Since your script is supposed to *move* a specific number of files from the list, two instances will at best move twice as many files.  Unless they even interfere with each other, then the number of moved files might be less.

In any case, this is probably a bad situation to begin with.  If you have any way of preventing two scripts running at the same time, you should do that.

If, however, you have no way of preventing two script instances from running at the same time, you should at least harden the scripts against errors:

mv "$REMOTE_FILE" "$SCRDRL" 2>/dev/null

Otherwise your scripts will produce error output (no good idea in a cron script).

Further, I hope that your `${TMP_LIST_FILE}` is not the same in both instances (you could use `$$` in it to avoid that); otherwise they'd even overwrite this temp file, in the worst case resulting in a corrupted file containing paths you do not want to move.

Comment: Suposed what "targdir" is a mounted remote folder. And instances runs on different servers. But now I'm testing setup with one server with two instances. System should get some piece of data and process it without knowing about exist other instances or not.